# Call Cypress command only when it is needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cypress

For a specific requirement, we need to execute cypress only when it is needed, it is possible that we can expose a rest api, that inside has cypress command, simple like this:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/randomURL',(req,res,next) => {
    cy.visit(URL)
    cy.someCustomCommand()
    return res.status(200).send('Test');
});
```

It's this approach possible? Without calling cypress.run()?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also, I'm wondering what kind of requirement would that be to justify this approach? Perhaps there's a better suited tool for this than UI test automation framework.

Comment: @Zaista We have app1 which has the UI and cypress, but there is another app2 that wants to test the app1 just calling specific endpoints to trigger the specific functionality. By chance do you know any tool that can achieve that? Thank you!!!